# Send JSON data from one page and receive dynamically from another page using AJAX when both page are open

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to send JSON data from page1 on submit button click and try to receive this data dynamically from page2 using AJAX and print the data in console. I don't know the proper syntax to do this. One suggested code which is not appropriate. The code is given:

page1:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $x = "ok";
    echo json_encode($x);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is page is sending json data on submit button press</p>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
</head>

<body>
<p>Get json data from page1 dynamically using ajax</p>

<script>
    setInterval(checkVariableValue, 5000);
    function checkVariableValue() {
         $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'page1.php',
              datatype: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
         });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I write to make it works properly?

Comment: what is datatype jsonn? :)

Comment: opsss, it will be json. Typing mistake.

Comment: try it again...  and change if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ to if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')){

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in

Comment: @Murad, Upon submitting the form, you can store the value in `$_SESSION` & then you can get that Session value on ajax request. I think it is simple now.

Comment: Ahh my bad, sorry, in comment so hard to paste code, if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

Comment: It's working @Peter.

Comment: @Agam Banga, What I have to write to do this with session variable?

Comment: @Peter, It is printing in the console before clicking submit button

Comment: @Murad, I have added an answer. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST["submit"])){
       $value = 'I am test'; //can be any value
       $_SESSION['key'] = $value;
    } else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')){
       echo $_SESSION['key'];
    }
```

Comment: How to grab it from other page ajax?

Comment: What is printing in 'console.log'

Comment: are you getting the value from session in `console.log`?

Comment: Yes, I have two question.
1. Why else if part?
2. Before submit the button console is printing some error, how to fix the issue?

Comment: You are sending two POST requests on a single page.
One is from Form & other is from ajax. So when we get the POST from `Form`, we need to update the session value & when we get POST from ajax, we need to return the value from session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142500/discussion-between-agam-banga-and-murad).

Comment: Why is this answer upwoted? What is that strange else if statement? These are same

Comment: @Peter One is for form submission & other is from post method via ajax call

Comment: Yes, but it's wrong, it should be right to use ajax request with GET and make the difference based on the method not on the submit button value. This solution is ugly and teaches users to solve their similar problems wrong.

Comment: @Peter He was using POST already, that's why i didn't ask him to change as he may be passing some parameters in future. I answered according to the question. I don't think that it is the reason for downvoting an answer.